# optimization problem with only non convex object function as a convex optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Is it possible to rewrite an optimization problem with only non convex object function as a convex optimization?

I think it is impossible but am having a hard time proving it.

EDIT: What I mean by rewrite is to find equivalent convex problem, by maybe rewriting the objective function or transferring part of the objective function to the constraints.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite" here? Obviously a non-convex objective function is always non-convex, no matter how you choose to express it. If you're allowed to change the objective function, in what ways are you allowing it to change?

Comment: I'd assume he meant equivalent problem which is convex. Namely, assume having $ g \left( x \right) $ which is non convex, are there cases where we can construct $ f \left( x \right) $ which is convex such that $ \arg \min_{x} g \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{x} f \left( x \right) $. Of course this is true (See the ideas behind Majorization Minimization).

Comment: No, if it was possible to always do that (using a strategy which takes less time than actually solving the original problem), we would not have to have the area of non-convex optimization, as we simply could use this magic conversion trick, and solve a convex problem instead. (Well, it could be that it was possible to convert all non-convex problems to intractable convex programs perhaps, but that is probably not what you intended)

Comment: There's also the fact that the minimisers of a convex function are convex, so if the non-convex function is minimised on a non-convex set, then there cannot be an equivalent convex problem.

Comment: There are some few specific examples of situations where a monotonic transformation can convexify a non-convex minimization objective (or equivalently make a non-concave maximization objective concave.)  See for example the maximization of a log-concave objective function.